# How to save output in .csv after every loop without overwriting in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to save my output in .csv. When I am running my while loop and saving the output, My output is only saving for the last iteration.
Its not saving my all iteration value.

Also, I want to skip the zero value rows while printing my output.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd `#pandas library
sample = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv ("Sample.csv")) #importing .csv as pandas DataFrame

i = 0
while (i <= 23):
    print('Value for', i) `#i vale`
    sample2 = (sample[sample['Hour'] == i])`#Data for every hour`
    sample3 = (sample2[(sample2['GHI']) == (sample2['GHI'].max(0))]) `#Max value from sample3 DataFrame`
    sample3 = sample3.loc[sample3.ne(0).all(axis=1)]`ignoring all rows having zero values`
    print(sample3)  `print sample3`
    sample3.to_csv('Output.csv')`trying to save for output after every iteration`
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: if you want to save after iteration, you should rename your output after each iteration, e.g. `sample3.to_csv(f'Output{i}.csv')`.

Comment: Or you can use `mode='a'` inside to_csv() to append.

Comment: Thank you your input. yes I am able to get my all data without overwriting. but I am getting all the row header after my all iteration. e.g.  Year Month Day Hour Minute DHI DNI GHI Dew Point Surface Albedo Wind Direction Wind Speed Temperature Pressure
3917 2005 6 13 5 30 34 363 78 10 0.129 116.5 4 13 1010
 Year Month Day Hour Minute DHI DNI GHI Dew Point Surface Albedo Wind Direction Wind Speed Temperature Pressure
3918 2005 6 13 6 30 62 656 265 11 0.129 134.1 4.8 16 1010
 Year Month Day Hour Minute DHI DNI GHI Dew Point Surface Albedo Wind Direction Wind Speed Temperature Pressure

Comment: Its repeatedly printing row title after every iteration. I dont want to do it

Comment: @ShriganeshPatil what you can do is `if i == 0`, then add `header = True` in the to_csv() method. else `header = False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other way of doing what you want to do is to get rid of your loop, like this :

```
sample_with_max_ghi = sample.assign(max_ghi=sample.groupby('Hour')['GHI'].transform('max'))
sample_filtered = sample_with_max_ghi[sample_with_max_ghi['GHI'] == sample_with_max_ghi['max_ghi']]
output_sample = sample_filtered.loc[sample_filtered.ne(0).all(axis=1)].drop('max_ghi', axis=1)
output_sample.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Some explanations :

1.

```
sample_with_max_ghi = sample.assign(max_ghi=sample.groupby('Hour')['GHI'].transform('max'))
```

This line add a new column to your dataframe containing the max of `GHI` column for your group of `Hour`

2.

```
sample_filtered = sample_with_max_ghi[sample_with_max_ghi['GHI'] == sample_with_max_ghi['max_ghi']]
```

This line filters only rows where the `GHI` value is actually the max of its `Hour` group

3.

```
output_sample = sample_filtered.loc[sample_filtered.ne(0).all(axis=1)].drop('max_ghi', axis=1)
```

And apply the last filter to get rid of the 0 values rows

Comment: Thank you this code is also working very appropriately

Answer (score 0):

while the loop is running adding the value at every loop to rename the csv file will make it to look unique and solve your problem.. eg:

```
import pandas as pd `#pandas library
sample = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv ("Sample.csv")) #importing .csv as pandas DataFrame

i = 0
while (i <= 23):
    print('Value for', i) `#i vale`
    sample2 = (sample[sample['Hour'] == i])`#Data for every hour`
    sample3 = (sample2[(sample2['GHI']) == (sample2['GHI'].max(0))]) `#Max value from sample3 DataFrame`
    sample3 = sample3.loc[sample3.ne(0).all(axis=1)]`ignoring all rows having zero values`
    print(sample3)  `print sample3`
    sample3.to_csv(str(i)+'Output.csv')`trying to save for output after every iteration`
    i = i + 1
```