# How to read all files in single folder and import for data operation in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing some data analysis on 120 .csv/.xlsx files. I have to segregate the data. and I have to perform following operation.

" [How to save output in .csv after every loop without overwriting in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433213/how-to-save-output-in-csv-after-every-loop-without-overwriting-in-pandas) "

Each files have different file name.

I don't have Idea about which code should I have to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not super sure what you're asking. Something like this?

```
def main():

    from pathlib import Path
    from contextlib import ExitStack

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        csv_files = [stack.enter_context(path.open()) for path in Path(".").glob("*.csv")]
        # Do stuff with csv_files

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: thank you @user10987432